# java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'msg' cannot be null

Tags: java, mysql, spring, database, hibernate

I am establishing a one to many relationship between two entities "Event" and "Message". Event is the parent and message is the child. Whenever I tried to insert a row of data into "Message" I always get **java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'msg' cannot be null** which I certainly have entered it. When I set msg property to be nullable then the error message becomes **java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'user_name' cannot be null**. It seems mysql did not get any argument from Postman. Been trying to look for answers for whole day but can't find one, please help me out. The following is the code.

Event Entity

```
package com.example.springsecurityjwt.models;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name ="Event")
public class Event {

    @Id
    private int eventId;
    private int mountainId;
    private String event_name;
    private String leader;
    private Date date;
    private int eventType;
    private int minNumOfMember;
    private int numOfMember;
    private String description;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "integer default 0")
    private int status;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "eventId", referencedColumnName = "eventId")
    List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Message Entity

```
package com.example.springsecurityjwt.models;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.util.Date;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name ="Message")
public class Message {

    @Id
    private int messageId;
    private int eventId;
    private String userName;
    private String msg;
    private Date date;

}
```

MessageService

```
@Service
public class MessageService {

    @Autowired
    private MessageRepository messageRepository;

    public Message addMessage(Message message){
       return messageRepository.save(message);

    }
}
```

MessageController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/message")
public class MessageController {

    @Autowired
    private MessageService messageService;

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public Message addMessage(@Validated Message message){
        return messageService.addMessage(message);
    }
}
```

Dependencies

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-security-jwt</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId> <!-- or jjwt-gson if Gson is preferred -->
            <version>0.11.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Message table in mysql
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0Qam.png)

Error message

```
Hibernate: insert into message (date, event_id, msg, user_name, message_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2020-06-28 20:25:37.125  WARN 16204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
2020-06-28 20:25:37.125 ERROR 16204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'msg' cannot be null
2020-06-28 20:25:37.140 ERROR 16204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'msg' cannot be null
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:117) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1092) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1040) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.20.jar:8.0.20]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you're parsing json correctly? I can see you're using spring, then you'll probably have to use `@RequestBody`:

```
@PostMapping("/add")
public Message addMessage(@Validated @RequestBody Message message){
    return messageService.addMessage(message);
}
```

I suggest placing a breakpoint there to see whether `Message` object is constructed properly.

Comment: It turns out I was stupid enough to forget to add @RequestBody just like you said and failed to notice it the whole day. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used email for the entity class and used email_id for the dto class. The request sent was from the entity class, which is disconnected from the dto. Hence the error.